# Why is the SNAP version of libre office so much slower then the APT version

Tags: apt, libreoffice, snap

The Snap version of libre office is obscenely slow. The Apt version works just fine. How can that be?

Comment: Snap-provided software should not run noticeably faster or slower than the same application packaged another way. If you can reliably reproduce a significant difference, then please file a bug or issue with the snap author, AND please raise the issue in the forum at snapcraft.io.